# Error when launching Spring Cloud Task batch-job on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-task

I registered the batch-job task from https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/io/spring/cloud/batch-job/1.0.0.RELEASE/ in Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

When launching the task I see the error

CF-UnprocessableEntity(10008): Task must have a droplet. Specify droplet or assign current droplet to app.

These are the commands I executed to register this task

app register --name batch-job --type task --uri maven://io.spring.cloud:batch-job:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE

task create myjob --definition batch-job

task list

task launch myjob

task execution list

Appreciate if someone can point what I am i missing.

Answer (score 1):

It means your app is not deployed correctly. Look at cf push log for more details.

I had the similar error where it was not determining the buildpack.

I have added below in my pom.xml so PCF automatically detect the buildpack.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually observed when the default API timeout (30s) is not enough to successfully deploy and launch the Task application. You can override the default behavior by setting a larger value via `SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_TASK_API_TIMEOUT`. Please review the [configuration section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuration_reference) in the reference guide for more details.

FYI: We recently changed the default timeout experience to 360s via [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry#192](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-cloudfoundry/pull/192). This is included in the current 1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT build.